# Elseif not working on Apache2.4

Tags: web-server, configuration, apache-2.4

I want to redirect to maintenance page people which have NOT a specific header (my admins).

So people which have a `USERID` header in the following list should not enter into the `Elsif` condition, and enter into the else one.

```
<Elseif "true && !%{HTTP:USERID} in { '789456', '456123' }">
    Header echo USERID
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/maintenance.html
    RewriteRule ^ /maintenance.html [R=302]
</Elseif>
<Else>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/ie.html [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/maintenance.html
    RewriteRule ^ / [R=302]
</Else>
```

The `true` boolean just help me to turned maintenance mode ON and OFF.

If I refresh the site on my browser I'm redirected to the maintenance page, and I can see the header `USERID:789456` on my response.

As far as I understand if it print me `USERID:789456` it should failed into the condition, but it doesn't...

What did I misunderstand?